# Regex to remove file path

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, filepath

I want to remove some part of this file path:

> C:\Users\room\Desktop\dev\myapp\node/**data**//test/nested/74201820018PM-AI2.jpg

I want the path name after the 'data' like **/test/nested/74201820018PM-AI2.jpg**

Edit: This file path comes from windows OS. I want regex to work for both windows or linux.

Comment: How about: /data\/(\/.*?)$/   https://regex101.com/r/ENatkd/1

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use **[a regex](https://regex101.com/r/1bG4T7/1)** with a matching group, something like this:

```
/\/data\/(.+)$/
```

**Explanation:**

- `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- `data` matches the characters data literally (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

*1st Capturing Group (.+)*

- `.+` matches any character (except for line terminators) - Quantifier — `+` Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line
  terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

**Note:**

To make it compatible with both `Windows` and `Linux` paths you need to update **[the regex](https://regex101.com/r/1bG4T7/2)** so it takes both `/` and `\` into account:

```
[\/\\]data[\/\\](.+)$
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "C:\Users\room\Desktop\dev\myapp\node/data//test/nested/74201820018PM-AI2.jpg";
var match = str.match(/\/data\/(.+)$/);
console.log(match[1]);
```

### EDIT:

**To remove the first part of this file `path`**

You can use **[an inversed regex](https://regex101.com/r/1bG4T7/4)** to match the first part of the `path` and remove it from the `string`, using `.replace(regex, '')`:

```
^(.+[\/\\]data[\/\\])
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = `C:\\Users\\room\\Desktop\\dev\\myapp\\node/data//test/nested/74201820018PM-AI2.jpg`;

const regex = /^(.+[\/\\]data[\/\\])/;

var matched = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(matched);
```

Comment: Why need to get result from an array just to replace something? is it memory efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @Jaz This is how regex matches, the array represents the matches, it won't have impacts on the memory as you can just ommit the array declaration part and use `str.match(/\/data\/(.+)$/)[1]`, directly.

Comment: @Jaz Note that you can also use `replace(regex, '')` method over the path using an inversed regex that will match the first part of the path.

Comment: [\/\\]data[\/\\](.+)$   this one for both windows and linux is not working. how i can use it with replace?

Comment: @Jaz I made an edit to the answer so it uses `.replace()` check it, make sure to escape the `/` in the string.

Comment: Actually, my file path contains single backslash. So this one does not work with it. Is is possible to ignore both single and double backslash?

Comment: @Jaz You need to use the escaped `//` so they can be matched with the regex, otherwise you can just use the first option. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It checks if the rest of the characters is preceded by the string `data/`

```js
var str = "C:\Users\room\Desktop\dev\myapp\node/data//test/nested/74201820018PM-AI2.jpg"; 
console.log(str.match(/(?<=data\/).+$/)[0]);
```

Comment: I don't want to have file extension checked. Filename or extension could be anything

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that:

- `data` in your path may at some time change to other string,
- the actual "cut point" is **double slash** (less likely to change).

So your code should:

- match the initial part of the string, up to the double slash (including),
- replace is with a **single** slash.

Something like: `result = my_path.replace(/.*\/\//,"/");`